# Implicit Differentiation Help!

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Could use some help with this -

Given $e^L + KL = Ke^K$, we are being asked to find $\frac{dL}{dK}$. I think O need to use implicit differentiation, but I am really not sure how to do it!

Comment: So we have $$e^{L(K)}+KL(K)=Ke^K$$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the implicit function $$f(K,L)=e^L + KL - Ke^K=0$$ Now
$$\frac{\partial f(K,L)}{\partial K}=L-e^K (K+1)\qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\partial f(K,L)}{\partial L}=e^L+K$$
Now, using the implicit function theorem
$$\frac{dL}{dK}=-\frac{\frac{\partial f(K,L)}{\partial K} } { \frac{\partial f(K,L)}{\partial L}}=\frac{e^K (K+1)-L}{K+e^L}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to do implicit differentiation.  Some methods have you differentiate respect to a particular variable, but, the way I prefer is to just do differentiation *without* being with respect to a particular variable, and then solve for the derivative you are looking for.  So, instead of the derivative rule for $y = u^n$ being $\frac{dy}{du} = nu^{n-1}$, I instead have the differential rule $dy = nu^{n-1}\, du$.  Then I can algebraically divide by $du$ if I want to find $\frac{dy}{du}$.

So, in your case, we have:
$$
e^L + KL = Ke^K
$$
Differentiating both sides gives us:
$$
d\left(e^L + KL\right) = d\left(Ke^K\right) \\
d\left(e^L\right) + d\left(KL\right) = d\left(Ke^K\right) \\
e^L\,dL + K\,dL + L\,dK = Ke^K\,dK + e^K\,dK
$$

now we just need to gather our terms together so we can solve for $\frac{dL}{dK}$:
$$
e^L\,dL + K\,dL + L\,dK = Ke^K\,dK + e^K\,dK \\
e^L\,dL + K\,dL = Ke^K\,dK + e^K\,dK - L\,dK \\
\left(e^L + K\right)\,dL = \left(Ke^K + e^K - L\right)\,dK \\
\frac{dL}{dK} = \frac{Ke^K + e^K - L}{e^L + K}
$$
More information about this method of implicit differentiation can be found [here](https://journals.blythinstitute.org/ojs/index.php/cbi/article/view/29).